# Che vuol dire "poderi precedentemente per sentenza pendente"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Furto della Cassa Comunale, contenente somme vigenti, parte innumerario, parte in fede di 
>   credito; saccheggio in diverse case civili con appropriazione di somme, fede di credito, gioje, oggetti d'oro e di argento accompagnato da incendî di libri creditorî e di ogni documento appartenente a fortune private; devastazione a frutta, a ricolta, nei campi estesa e generalizzata per eserzione degli anarchisti; appropriazione di case, e di **poderi precedentemente per sentenza pendente**; o volontariamente, e per atti autentici o laicali, scrocco di somme per componende, e minacce di danno, o di vita, arresti arbitrarii, ed ogni altra abusiva escandescenza, e tutto questo iniziato al grido di Viva Vittorio Emmanuele - Viva Garibaldi, e all'ombra del Vessillo della rigenerazione, che aveva servito di mezzo a disarmare preventivamente, ed agglomerare vittorie designate; come le prime ad essere immolate, e che dovevan essere seguite da altre, cui fortuite circostanze trovarono, e che dovevano formare i prodromi di un numero di reati e di scelleraggini, poscia parte consumati, parte per divina misericordia non commessi.

Si tratta di parte di un documento emesso dalla Commissione Speciale di Patti  nel 1860.

Non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "poderi precedentemente per sentenza pendente", malgrado conoscere il significato delle singole parole. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Il testo è intenzionalmente oscuro e in burocratese, ma *poderi* qui è chiaramente da unirsi a *case*. Vale a dire *appropriazione (di case, e di poderi) precedentemente (per sentenza pendente)*. Purtroppo non mi è chiaro il senso complessivo della frase.

Comment: Sono quasi sicuro che "sentenza pendente" significa che non è ancora definitiva; significherà quindi che l'appropriazione dei poderi è stata fatta prima ancora che ce ne fosse il pieno diritto dovuto ad una sentenza passata in guidicato.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Sono d'accordo con te, ma mi sembra quasi che manchi una parola alla frase: avrebbe molto più senso se ci fosse un *espropriati* o simili tra *precedentemente* e *per*...